# Cannot /get on route hot reload Angular Yeoman Grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, gruntjs, yeoman-generator-angular

I am using yeoman angular and grunt on a project, and once I turned on HTMLmode for the pretty URLs, I get errors when I got reload and have to back to the index.

I have tried adding `<base href='/' />` to the index, but that hasn't helped any.

Is there a good solution for this problem I am unaware of? Do I need to modify the grunt file somehow, or the app.js file?